# I cannot make "commands" in chrome extension work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension. I am facing some problems. I am unable to make the [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) in chrome extension work. Below is given the code that I have written.
Here is my `manifest.json` file.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "This is just a test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "toggle-feature-foo": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+1"
            },
            "description": "Show Alert"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `content.js` file.

```
alert("This is just a test 3");
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    alert('Command:', command);
});
```

**The problem:** I can see the first alert. But when I press *Ctrl+Shift+1* I am unable to see the second alert. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content Script` cannot use `chrome.* APIs`, with the exception of:

1. `extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )`
   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL
2. `i18n`
   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n
3. `runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )`
   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime
4. `storage`
   https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

**Solution:**

Add your code in `background page` or use `message passing` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: I have written a background.js script. I have added it oin manifest.json file. It is still not working.

Comment: Here is my backgrund.js file

Comment: ```
alert("Alert from background");
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
 console.log("I found a command");
});
```

Comment: From where are you checking the console.log?

Comment: under chrome://extensions/ --> under your extension --> inspect views : background page??

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work even i I use alert.

Comment: That code works for me. Try hitting the shortcut on various pages.